# Error "The view at '~/Views/Page/home.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TViewData>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TViewData>"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view

I've just installed MVC2 and I've got a view that looks like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Home.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>    
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home
</asp:Content>    
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">    
    <h2>Home</h2>    
</asp:Content>
```

And the controller is just returning the view. But when I run the page I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Views/Page/home.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl.

Comment: Are you sure that the code you've shown belongs to `~/Views/Page/home.aspx`?

Comment: you solved my issue by asking a question.  thank you.  I saw you had Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage and used it, now I can use reportviewer   in my MVC5 app!

Comment: May be you did just forget to change the auto-generated base class you inherit from in your CodeBehind-File, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47433765/3423823 - at least that was my problem, I stumbled across multiple questions that did not suggest this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might unintentionally have two versions of the MVC framework loaded into the same application.  To confirm, download MVC 2 Futures from http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742.  There is a file **MvcDiagnostics.aspx** in this ZIP file.

1. Copy MvcDiagnostics.aspx to the root of your web project.
2. Reproduce the error.
3. After reproducing the error, go to /MvcDiagnostics.aspx and see if it complains (will be in bold red lettering) about multiple versions of the framework being loaded.  The tool should suggest a resolution if this is the case.

Don't forget to delete MvcDiagnostics.aspx from your project when you are done.

Comment: +1: I had the same problem, and in my case there were indeed two different versions of MVC2 loaded. I didn't know about the diagnostics thingie, however. Good to know.

Comment: Yep that was the problem, I ended up just having to mark the MVC dll as copy local on the web project & it fixed the problem, thanks!

Comment: Thanks.It helped me to migrate solution from MVC 1.0 to MVC 4.0

Comment: @Levi The System.Web.Mvc is 5.2.40  version but the issue remains.

Comment: @Levi I made an upgrade to MVC from 5.2.4 to 5.2.7 version.....  Nothing the problem is there

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error upgrading my MVC 1.0 project to MVC 2.0. If you are doing this have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx

Double check your web.config against a new MVC 2.0 project.

Answer (score 1):

Doing either a `batch->build->clea`n at the solution level OR a clean at the project level usually takes care of this if you have already done the due diligence of removing/replacing the undesired version(s) of `System.Web.Mvc` from project references and *.config files...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Upgrader](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008)

Best to do this with your code under source control, that way you can eye-ball everything that is changes. It updates your javascript which I didn't want so I reverted that, and only kept the changes it makes to the web.config for razor.

Be sure to read about what it does and what it doesn't support on [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for myself by having my custom view engine inherit RazorViewEngine directly.

```
public class MainViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MainViewEngine()
    {...
}}
```

And then registering that viewengine in the Global.asax file Application_Start event:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MainViewEngine());
```

Clearly this assumes that you are using Razor.

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference to System.Web.Mvc.dll file in your reference. Make sure its pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

If its pointing to the one under ASP.NET MVC 4 directory then open your project file in a notepad. Look for

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc">
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

This should be changed to

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

This will help to point to the specific MVC version